# How to display error message in view page using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to display the error message  using php.I am explaining my code below.

> addcomplain.php:

```
<div style="color:#F00; text-align:center;"><?php echo $error?></div>
<form name="billdata" id="billdata"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onSubmit="javascript:return checkForm();" action="complain.php">
</form>
```

Suppose i have a form like above and when i submit the below file is called.

> complain.php:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM medilink_complain WHERE email='".$email."'";
$selres = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($selres ) > 0)
   {
    $error = "Email Id already exists!";

    }
```

when the above error will come,i need it should display just above the form.In my case i am not getting anything.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Store your error in session and echo the session data above form.

Comment: If i will store it in session it will display everytime.

Comment: unset the session at the end of the page.

Comment: Not if you unset it after showing...

Comment: @Blaatpraat : Can you write your answer please.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Just to be sure: are you including (include/require) **addcomplain.php** in **complain.php**?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

addcomplain.php:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION["error"])){
    echo '<div style="color:#F00; text-align:center;">'. $_SESSION["error"] .'</div>';;
    unset($_SESSION["error"]);
} ?>
```

complain.php:

```
session_start();
$sql="SELECT * FROM medilink_complain WHERE email='".$email."'";
$selres = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($selres ) > 0)
   {
        $_SESSION["error"] = "Email Id already exists!";
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a session.

Merge your code into 1 file. Show only `$error` if he is *not null*, like so:

```
<?php
   $error = null;

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
       $sql="SELECT * FROM medilink_complain WHERE email='".$email."'";
       $selres = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

       if(mysqli_num_rows($selres ) > 0) {
           $error = "Email Id already exists!";
       }
    }

?>

<div style="color:#F00; text-align:center;"><?= (!is_null($error) ? $error : ''); ?></div>
     <form name="billdata" id="billdata"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onSubmit="javascript:return checkForm();" action="complain.php">
     </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

complain.php:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM medilink_complain WHERE email='".$email."'";
$selres = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($selres ) > 0)
   {
    $_SESSION["error"] = "Email Id already exists!";

    }
```

In addcomplain.php :

```
$error = $_SESSION["error"];
unset($_SESSION["error"]);
    <div style="color:#F00; text-align:center;"><?php echo $error?></div>
    <form name="billdata" id="billdata"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onSubmit="javascript:return checkForm();" action="complain.php">
    </form>
```

Comment: In which page i have to add above.

Answer (score 0):

You can write couple of functions to make it easier:

```
function setMessage($message){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = $message;
}

function showMessage(){
    echo $_SESSION['msg'];
    unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}
```

complain.php:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($selres ) > 0)
{
    $error = "Email Id already exists!";
    setMessage($error);
}
```

addcomplain.php:

```
<div style="color:#F00; text-align:center;"><?php echo showMessage(); ?></div>
```

Note: make sure you have started the session, using `session_start()` in the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use Session object for this.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM medilink_complain WHERE email='".$email."'";
$selres = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($selres ) > 0)
{
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Email Id already exists!";

}
```

The display like this.

```
<?php 
    $error = "";
    if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) 
    { 
        $error = $_SESSION['error']; 
        unset($_SESSION['error']); 
    } 
  ?>
  <div style="color:#F00; text-align:center;">
      <?php echo $error; ?>
  </div>

  <form name="billdata" id="billdata"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onSubmit="javascript:return checkForm();" action="complain.php">
  </form>
```

Comment: I did as per you but its not coming.It redirecting to complain.php page.

Comment: @satya Just redirect to your addcomplain.php page after setting the error into session. It will show if it finds any error..

Answer (score 0):

### complain.php

```
    <?php
    $sql="SELECT * FROM medilink_complain WHERE email='".$email."'";
    $selres = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($selres ) > 0)
    {
       $error = "Email Id already exists!";
    } else {
       $error = '';
    }
    include 'addcomplain.php'; // <----
    ?>
```

### addcomplain.php

```
    <html>
    <body>    
    <div style="color:#F00; text-align:center;"><?php echo $error?></div>
    <form name="billdata" id="billdata"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onSubmit="javascript:return checkForm();" action="complain.php">
    <input value="test" />
    </form>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

...works for me! No session variable needed.

Comment: addcomplain.php gives an `undefined` if the Email Id not exists ;-)

Comment: @Schellingerht Right and thanks :-)) I made an update.

Comment: @hherger : Ok,But the typed data is getting blank in all field of the form.

Comment: @satya I looked at what you have shown us. We cannot see what data from the form you are sending to the server. And, sorry, I can not invent your form ;-)

Comment: @satya You know that form fields transferred are available to a scripts as **$_POST['fieldname']** variables, right? Otherwise it's a good idea to put **var_dump($_POST);** into the _complain.php_ script to show what is transferred.